# How to import TStringList and TStrings type to WSDL

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap, wsdl

I have the following definition on `types` on wsdl of webservice that i working with, but when i try to import the wsdl using SoapUI i get message that TStringList and TString is not defined, i do a little research and looks like this is a type of Borland Delphi, there is a workaround to make this wsdl work? There a import that i'm missing?

```
    <xs:schema xmlns="urn:Custom" targetNamespace="urn:Custom">
        <xs:complexType name="TStringList">
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:extension base="TStrings">
                    <xs:sequence/>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
```

Comment: You're right. TStrings is an abstract base class in Delphi, representing a list of strings, and has various descendant classes. TStringList implements an in-memory stringlist with a bunch of utility methods. I don't really know how that should be a problem, though. The `name` and `base` are 'just' names, as is made clear in [XML Schema complexType Element](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_complextype.asp). Can you elaborate a bit more on the tools you use, the staps you take, and the exact errors you get? Importing 'using' SOAP for instance doesn't make much sense, since SOAP is a protocol.

Comment: Sorry, its was a type i mean "SoapUI", when i try to import de WSDL to it he give me a message that cannot find TStringList type, so i was thinking about changing the original xml of WSDL to fix this and could test the service.  This is my WSDL: https://pastebin.com/2XavqXrx i change a litle bit to hidden because is a private wsdl.

Comment: On your exposed interfaces and types they use, replace TStrings/TStringList with TStringDynArray instead, this will be automatically translated to SOAP string[] array type. (You can still continue to use string lists on the implementation side, just convert to/from string arrays to fulfill the interface contract.)

Comment: Thanks @OndrejKelle this works smootly, i changed to `<xs:complexType name="TStringDynArray"></xs:complexType>` and then referece by `ns2:TStringDynArray` is this, right?